# What have I done wrong with this simple template class?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates

I've written a little class to assist in conversions to and from MSVC's clunky types:

```
template <class FromType>
struct convert
{
    convert(FromType const &from)
        :   from_(from) {}
    operator LARGE_INTEGER() {
        LARGE_INTEGER li;
        li.QuadPart = from_;
        return li;
    }
private:
    FromType const &from_;
};
```

Later I do this:

```
convert(0)
```

And get this error message from MSVC:

> 1>e:\src\cpfs\libcpfs\device.cc(41): error C2955: 'convert' : use of class template requires template argument list
>
> 1>          e:\src\cpfs\libcpfs\device.cc(17) : see declaration of 'convert'

I thought that `FromType` could be inferred from the integer I am passing? What is going on?

Comment: U need to do something like this convert<integer>(0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Class templates are never instantiated implicitly.  Given the class definition you gave, you'd have to say:

```
convert<int>(0)
```

...to invoke that class's constructor.

With default template arguments, you could improve (?) it to:

```
template <class FromType = int>
struct convert
{ /* ... */ };
```

and then invoke it as:

```
convert<>(0)
```

...but I'm afraid that's the best you can do with a class template.  You might instead want to use a function template that instantiates class objects for you:

```
template <typename FromType>
convert<FromType> make_convert(FromType from) {
   return convert<FromType>(from);
}
```

This is more or less the approach used in std::make_pair() for example.

Comment: Thanks. I went with a convert factory and converter class. Later I threw them out and did it manually but meh :)